# Model URN security issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, urn

I have noticed that I can view the svf model of another user If I have his model urn, is there any way to protect other users to view my models?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be able to see a URN Viewable with the access token for that bucket, meaning there must be a match between URN and access token to view a file.

If you are seeing a different scenario, can you edit your question with details?